# Git error: RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400 send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet

Tags: git, github, git-commit, private-repository

I'm trying to upload a number of files and folders to my private GitHub repository. However, when I open my private repository on GitHub, I can't see the files and folders that I've pushed.

I've been using the command `git push origin master` to push my code.

I'm receiving the following error message:

> RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400
> send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet

Pic of Error Message:
[image]

How do I resolve this error and view the files and folders in my private GitHub repository?

Answer (score 1):

If you're encountering errors while pushing to a remote Git repository, it might not necessarily be your internet connection; it could be related to the buffer size.

#### Solutions:

1. **Increase the buffer size**: You can adjust the buffer size to prevent this error. Run the following command in your terminal:

   ```bash
   git config http.postBuffer 524288000
   ```
2. **Push smaller batches of changes**: If you're attempting to push a large number of changes at once, it could overwhelm the remote repository. Consider pushing smaller batches of changes instead.
3. **Contact GitHub support**: If none of the above solutions work, it might be beneficial to reach out to GitHub support for further assistance.

These steps should help address the issue you're experiencing with pushing to the remote repository.

The answer originally comes from this [discussion](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/49789#discussioncomment-5276609)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

1. first check your connection.
2. make changes stage and commit, with the command => git add . and git commit -m "message"
3. run git push origin branch-name